# Graph Api for getting whole objects schema

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api

I have searched a lot but didn't find so putting this question here -

Is there any graph api to get list of objects name (photo,album..) and their data fields in json format?

Answer (score 3):

I assuming you are asking how to get a JSON representation in Java since Facebook's Graph API already returns objects in JSON format (eg. https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor)

You can use the RestFB Java API here: http://restfb.com/

To convert an Object to a JSON representation, just use the DefaultJsonMapper

```
User user = new User(); // RestFB entity of a Facebook User
DefaultJsonMapper mapper = new DefaultJsonMapper();
String toJson = mapper.toJson(user);
```

Comment: I have already implemented all graph api using spring-mvc.My problem is, I have to manually specify each object name like (friendslist,album..). what I want is to get list of all object name using graph api.

Comment: No i don't think that is possible. Why don't you use an existing Facebook API library?

Comment: Actually I have a requirement, in which I have to convert all objects and their data-fields as a table schema. Currently I am manually create this.If I get all objects name list and their data-fields from facebook,this will remove my boilerplate code a lot.

Comment: Well RestFB has everything. You could just go to their API and take a look at what you need to create ;)